# Populating input field with Jquery doesn't submit data to server

Tags: jquery, .net, forms

I have an input field that users can specify a dollar amount. This field works and when users fill out my form I can see all the entries they put.

What I'm trying to achieve is putting 3 buttons above this input that are suggested dollar amounts of 10, 50, and 100.

Achieving this with Jquery is quite simple. Heres my code.

HTML

```
<button class="btn" id="donateButton10" type="button">$10</button>
<button class="btn" id="donateButton50" type="button">$50</button>
<button class="btn" id="donateButton100" type="button">$100</button>
```

The form input in question

```
 <div class="left right10 d_bold">Donation Amount<span class="required-field">*</span>
    <div class="formInput"><telerik:RadNumericTextBox runat="server" ID="Amount" Type="Currency" Width="315" Height = "48" Font-Bold = "true" Font-Size = "18pt" /></div>
</div>
```

And the javascript to make it happen

```
<script>
    $("#donateButton10").click(function () {
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Amount").val("$10.00");
    });
    $("#donateButton50").click(function () {
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Amount").val("$50.00");
    });
    $("#donateButton100").click(function () {
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Amount").val("$100.00");
    });
</script>
```

Here's the problem. When the user fills out the box manually and submits it, theres no problem. The form validates and everything is great. But when a user instead populates the input box with a suggested amount, the form throws an error saying it has a missing input.

So I wrote some C# code to grab the value of the input box and write the value to my debug line.

```
string tester = Amount.Value.ToString();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(tester);
```

When I manually enter 10 I get the following output

```
10

The thread 0xcf8 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

And it works perfectly. When I actually push the 10 button and submit the form, the output shows nothing but the thread exiting. So I know that when a user is clicking on the button, even though the number gets placed in the box, the actual value isn't.

Is Jquery's .val not the right thing for this? Is there something I'm not considering? The part that really throws me off is if I set a

```
value = "10.00"
```

On the form and submit it, it works. Thats why i thought `.val` would work

Comment: my form is initialized on the server side and passed the browser. That weird ID is what my program generates for my input box. The problem was never the Jquery not populating the input field. The problem was that I was filling it with a string instead of an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously you have validation if the value is a number. Filling the `.val()` function with `$10` makes it not `===` to `int`

Comment: Wow. It seems obvious now. Pretty dumb mistake. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have to wait a few minutes before I can accept. Dont worry.